# Do shell script in Applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to understand some lines of code.
I think that this code checks if the password is correct or not.

Am I right?

```
do shell script "dscl . -passwd /Users/" & username & " " & pw & " llama"
do shell script "dscl . -passwd /Users/" & username & " lalala " & pw & ""
```

What is the "lalala"-parameter?

I do not know what it does stand for and what does it means?

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator in AppleScript is used for string-concatenation. So if we look at your script as if those variables were already filled in, we would see:

```
dscl . -passwd /Users/TEST_USER TEST_PASS lalala
dscl . -passwd /Users/TEST_USER lalala TEST_PASS
```

Now you can see what the script is really doing, which is invoking the `dscl` command. This is doing 2 things:

1. Changing the `TEST_USER`'s password from `TEST_PASS` to `lalala`
2. Changing the `TEST_USER`'s password from `lalala` to an empty string.

The `lalala` isn't particularly significant, it's merely being used a placeholder password to change from the original `TEST_PASS` to eventually an empty string.

Without seeing the rest of the script, I'd guess that this AppleScript is being used as a way to clear out or reset a user's password, given the username and their original password.